# Code which is free from problems of SQL Injection

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

I have a comments box in my website

```
<td id="commentsBox" class="xec" size="200"></td>
```

I use Javascript to read the comments box and create an XML string.

```
<ROWS><COMMENTS>My comments</COMMENTS></ROWS>
```

The XML string is passed to a stored procedure via java. (I have simplified the SQL Code and XML String for the purposes of the question)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DB].[TEST$ExecuteXML] @doc VARCHAR(max)
    ,@P_Result VARCHAR(max) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idoc INT;

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT
        ,@doc;



        INSERT INTO MyTable (
            COMMENTS
            ,UPDATE_DATE
            )
        SELECT COMMENTS
            ,getDate()
        FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/ROWS', 1) WITH (
                COMMENTS VARCHAR(200) 'COMMENTS'
                );


    SET @p_result = 1;
END
```

I have looked at sites dealing with SQL Injection such as https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx

Is it possible to enter something into the textbox that will be destructive to the database?

UPDATE

In response to @Linky I add here (part of) the Java code - although I am at a loss to understand how this could be problematic, as the premise of my question is that the SQL Server procedure could accept anything in the XML.

```
XMLObject br = new XMLObject(xmlString);
String result = br.update();

public class XMLObject {

    public static final int RESULT_FAILED = 0;
    public static final int RESULT_SUCCESS = 1;

    protected DBConnection dbConn = null;

    protected String theXML=null;

    public XMLObject(String theXML) {       
        this.theXML=theXML;
    }


    public String update() {
        String result;
        ArrayList<DBField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        fields.add(new DBField(DBField.STRING, theXML, false));
        result = DMLUtils.executeString("ExecuteXML", fields);
        return result;
    }
```

}

Comment: Usually the problem is in the code that calls the db command (either procedure or any other DML). 
Yes - it's still possible - it depends on how you call the Procedure from Java

Comment: To understand how it could be problematic see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection comes from allowing SQL data to become or be treated as SQL commands.  In your example you are keeping data and commands clearly delineated, and AFAIK, neither `OPENXML` nor `sp_xml_preparedocumen` can *on their own* be used cause injection.

So, in my professional opinion, this appears to be safe from injection.

Comment: You're right that the code shown seems to be safe - but only the shown code. IMHO it's still possible to be open to sql injection as the java-sql bridge is not shown

Comment: @Linky That's true of anything and would make the question "*Is this code safe*" always moot.  But it isn't moot, and it *is* important to be able to identify which code is safe and which is not.  This code, as presented, is safe.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to avoid SQL Injection attacks is to tie the content to a particular column.  Directly entering the users comments into the database opens you up to cross site scripting attacks if that data is ever displayed to the user.  I would suggest that you take this question to the [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/).